# Make hover resize element only affect the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [list of elements](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Yk2du/) that have a bit of information, and I want the user to be able to hover over an element to see more information.

However, doing something like:

```
$('a.song').each(function() {
  var origwidth = $(this).width();
  var origheight = $(this).height();
  $(this).hover(
    function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({width: origwidth * 2, height: origheight * 2});
    }, function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({width: origwidth, height: origheight});
  });
});
```

causes the element to affect the position of other elements (instead of simply overlapping), and the width expansion is limited by the `column-count: 5;` in the `ol` css rules.

How can we make it so when the element expands it simply covers over any overlapping elements instead of pushing them, and properly expand the width even with `column-count: 5;`?

Comment: You could use `position:absolute` on the element and  `max-width` on the container. You could clone it.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Yk2du/1/

You could use `position:absolute` on the element and set the width of the container.

In the jsfiddle I also used z-index to make sure the hovered element shows over the top of the others.

```
ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

ol li a {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

P.S. You can do this with CSS3 and no javascript.

Comment: You might also want to make the ones that are rightmost expand to the left instead of right.

Comment: @Popnoodles but this requires me to get rid of `column-count`. I have a large list of elements but I don't know how many I have, so I want to use `column-count` to make it 5 columns.

Comment: @theintellects I don't think I understood that part of the question and there was no `column-count: 5` in the jsfiddle. What is `column-count: 5` and what do you mean by "properly expand the width"?